# php regex must contain several words and must not contain others

Tags: php, regex

I need to create a php regex pattern that would return true if one or more certain words are in the string, but a number of others are not.

For example, let's say we want to allow the words 'and', 'this', 'then'; but then disallow the words 'dont', 'worry' and 'never'.

So the following sentences should be matches:
"I like this stuff"
"this and then"
"is then"
"me and you"

but the following should not:
"I never like this stuff"
"dont worry about it"
"dont worry about this and that"
"I never worry about that stuff"
"I never do something"

The real stickler is not just the combination of 'and' 'or' 'and not' operators, but also that the words/strings could come anywhere in the sentence.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

```
function isAllowedSentence($str)
{
    return (preg_match('/\b(and|this|then)\b/i', $str) && !preg_match('/\b(don\'t|worry|never)\b/i', $str));
}


echo isAllowedSentence('I like this stuff'); // true
echo isAllowedSentence('I never like this stuff'); // false
echo isAllowedSentence('I like Johnny Mathis'); // false
```

Comment: "The band sucks" shouldn't match

Comment: You may want to add `\b` word boundaries. Otherwise looks good. +1

Comment: Yeah. Thought of that right when you guys commented! Thanks. I added the boundaries.

Comment: This does not work very well in my case as I actually plan to populate a multi-dimensional array full of regex' and then compare a dynamic string to each array key for matches on-demand.

Comment: @user. I see. Your question didn't mention that so I did my best to answer with the information given. Your problem becomes a bit more difficult with the large number of words.

Answer (score 2):

"And" and "not" are harder to do with regex. It's can be easier to it using more than one

```
preg_match('/\b(?:and|this|then)\b/i', $str)
   &&
!preg_match('/\b(?:dont|worry|never)\b/i', $str)
```

But it can be done.

First, the negation:

```
preg_match('/\b(?:and|this|then)\b/i', $str)
   &&
!preg_match('/^(?: (?!\b(?:dont|worry|never)\b). )*\z/isx', $str)
```

Then combining them:

```
preg_match(
   '/
      ^
      (?= .* \b(?:and|this|then)\b )
      (?= (?: (?!\b(?:dont|worry|never)\b). )*\z )
   /isx',
   $str
)
```

This works in Perl. Not tested in PHP.

**Update**: PHP-ified the code. Removed stray slash.

Comment: This returns `Unknown modifier )` warning.

Comment: @webbiedave, Which one, "x"? That just allows the whitespace. You can remove the "x" if you also remove all the spaces and line breaks.

Comment: It's complaining about a parenthesis `Unknown modifier ')'` Not sure which one it's complaining about though.

Comment: There's a stray slash in that last regex: `\b/`

Comment: @webbiedave, it was due to the stray `/` @Alan Moore mentioned. Fixed.